# Questions regarding Layouts and Title Bars in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design an android activity layout, I am using Eclipse with ADT. The layout must look like the screenshot.

[image: layout]

My question is to achieve this layout is it better to nest linear layouts, or use a relative layout? which is better to manipulate programatically?

Also In order to have the title bars on top of every section or tab is there any inbuilt widget or do I need to set background or have some sort of a static imageview?

As you can clearly see the application is iOS based and i have to migrate it to android and I am new to android and still working on learning the UI basics. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In this case I would suggest you nest LinearLayouts - you'll find it easier to manipulate the UI using weights.

2) For title bars, you could just use TextViews. Create your title-bar backgrounds using drawable xmls (or use images if you want), and then set your TextView background to the specific drawable.